# Define arguments in a command

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, arguments, xskak, skak

I am using the `skak` and `xskak` packages to make notes about chess. Everytime I need to print a board, I have to manually set the optional parameters, like the code below:

```
\chessboard[
    %--> ADD PIECES TO THE BOARD:
        setwhite={Kd3, Bd4},
        addblack={Ke8, Pe2},
    %--> ARROW STYLE:
        pgfstyle=straightmove,
        arrow=stealth,
        linewidth=3pt,
        padding=1ex,
        color=red!75,
        shortenstart=1ex,
    %--> DRAW THE ARROWS
        markmoves={d3-e2},
        showmover=false,
    %--> HIGHLIGHT STYLE:
        color=green!50,
        pgfstyle=color,
        opacity=.3,
    %--> HIGHLIGHT SQUARES:
        colorbackfields={e4, e3, e2, d2, c2, c3, c4},
        ]
```

My question is: **how to define a command with some of these arguments?***

For example, say that I would like to create a command like this:

```
\newcommand{\ArrowStyle}{%
    pgfstyle=straightmove,
    arrow=stealth,
    linewidth=3pt,
    padding=1ex,
    color=red,
    shortenstart=1ex}
```

... so that I could simply write:

```
\chessboard[
    %--> ADD PIECES TO THE BOARD:
        setwhite={Kd3, Bd4},
        addblack={Ke8, Pe2},
    %--> ARROW STYLE:
        \ArrowStyle
    %--> DRAW THE ARROWS
        markmoves={d3-e2},
        showmover=false,
    %--> HIGHLIGHT STYLE:
        color=green!50,
        pgfstyle=color,
        opacity=.3,
    %--> HIGHLIGHT SQUARES:
        colorbackfields={e4, e3, e2, d2, c2, c3, c4},
        ]
```

However, this doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a small minimal document in which we can test things and we could play with. (E.g., though I've never used `xskak` so have no idea about its interfaces I'm rather good at programming (and sometimes I even skim over manuals), so I'm pretty I could've provided an answer -- this is just a general advice on how to get (better) answers earlier). Oh, and ignore @UlrikeFischer, creating the package to be able to answer questions is cheating!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a style, see the documentation of chessboard:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}


\begin{document}


\storechessboardstyle{arrowstyle}{%
    pgfstyle=straightmove,
    arrow=stealth,
    linewidth=3pt,
    padding=1ex,
    color=red,
    shortenstart=1ex}


\chessboard[
    %--> ADD PIECES TO THE BOARD:
        setwhite={Kd3, Bd4},
        addblack={Ke8, Pe2},
    %--> ARROW STYLE:
        style=arrowstyle,
    %--> DRAW THE ARROWS
        markmoves={d3-e2},
        showmover=false,
    %--> HIGHLIGHT STYLE:
        color=green!50,
        pgfstyle=color,
        opacity=.3,
    %--> HIGHLIGHT SQUARES:
        colorbackfields={e4, e3, e2, d2, c2, c3, c4},
        ]
 
\end{document}
```

[image]